# I'm trying to call a method from a textbox in winforms when the enter key is pressed and it's not working

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

The if statement is being checked until I hit enter then it goes straight to another method. My guess is there is something else on the form that is getting triggered when I hit enter but I can't find it despite my search.
I want to not have to put a button on the form to call this function, the button I had worked but I just want to be able to hit enter from my textbox input.

Here is my code below:

```
 private void textBox1firstName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                searchAD();
            }
        }

        private void textBox2lastName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                searchAD();
            }

        }
```

searchAD() is not getting called despite hitting enter. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the same issue using the KeyUp Event?

Comment: Yes, I tried the break point on if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) and it stopped there everytime I hit a key but when I hit enter it went to another method without hitting my searchAD(); method

Comment: @Sorceri I tried keypress and keydown with the same result. It's checking the keys but something else is getting called with the enter key on the form...how do you override this on my key.enter?

Comment: ok, you can step through the code to see what is being called once you apply your break point.  (did you put a break point on the searchAD() line?  Assume you are using VSStudio? FYI, As we cannot reproduce this: It is now a guessing game as to what is causing it.

Comment: The `form` has a `KeyDown` event, but also has a "AcceptButton" property, which hooks the [Enter] keypress and can call an event handler.  Are either of those set on the form?

Comment: @tgolisch that's it!!! AcceptButton is calling that method. So that's the enter button gahhhh   Thank you! I don't want to change the behavior on the rest of the form I have to be able to override that flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has a KeyDown event, but also has a "AcceptButton" property, which hooks the [Enter] keypress and can call an event handler. Check if there are event-handlers attached to either of those on the form.